# Compare two columns and return a list of values from the first column that don't exist in the second

Tags: google-sheets

I want a formula in column C to return a list, with any duplicates removed, of the values in column A that do not exist in column B.

I'm using UNIQUE to get the unique values in column A, but can't work out how to remove the values that also exist in column B.

Does anyone know the answer?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDWko.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

**`=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A;ISNA(MATCH(A2:A;B2:B2;0))))`**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this too:

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY(A2:B;"select A where not A matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|";1;B2:B)&"'";0))
```

or US notation:

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY(A2:B,"select A where not A matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|",1,B2:B)&"'",0))
```

[image]